# How does a browser calculate SVG text element height?

Tags: svg, browser

I have this structure
https://codepen.io/artemzwinger/pen/zEJoXd

```
<svg text-rendering="geometricPrecision" class="textSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text class="myText" y="30%">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|</text>
  <text class="myText" y="60%">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|</text>
</svg>
```

How does a browser calculate SVG text element height?

Comment: I need to place a `text` node to vertical center through `x` and `y` coords.

Comment: The browser calculates the bounding box of the text element as the closest rectangle enclosing the geometry of every glyph. - But I suspect this is not what you wanted to know. Do you think `y="30%"` has any relation to text height? It has not, it references the SVG viewport height.